# Is there any heartbeat like function?

Tags: special-functions

I'm looking for a function, where the result is something like this:

[image]

I tried to figure it out myself, but I have no idea how to manage it.
`f(x) = ...`

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The heart beat function for a dead guy is defined by $f(x)=0.$

Comment: Hodgkin-Huxley gives a system of differential equations whose solutions look pretty close. As in the normal pattern is a limit cycle.

Comment: Here's a fun little function if you're just going for the aesthetic: sin(x)^63 * sin(x+1.5)*8

Comment: The derivative of (cos(x))^x looks a little bit like that for x > 0 (in my opinion)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A silly answer would be "fit a spline to your curve", but the meaningful answer tries to extract information on the condition of the heart from the characteristic features of the electrocardiogram; there is an extensive literature on this problem, see for example:

[*Functional Data Analytic Approach of Modeling ECG
T-wave Shape to Measure Cardiovascular Behavior*](http://www.niss.org/sites/default/files/tr173.pdf).